# display a latex string with c++

Tags: c++, winapi, latex

I'm looking for a function that displays a LaTeX or a MathML string in a windows GUI app.

For example given: `char* myLaTeX = "\\dfrac{5}{3}";`

the function I'm looking for can display the formatted fraction in my window, in the logical coordinates i set.
Is there a way to do so just using the `DrawText()` or `TextOut()`?

Comment: Wishful thinking. You need a library. Very far from trivial. No one liner for you.

Comment: Search [softwarerecs.se] for a C++ library.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a Smalltalk programmer so let me tell you how I've worked this out:

1. Use the `EM_GETOLEINTERFACE` message to get an `IRichEditOle` interface
2. Use this interface to `QueryInterface` `ITextDocument2`
3. Use `GetSelection` and then `SetText` to output `'5/3'` (the `String`)
4. Use `Range` and `Select` to select all (i.e., `'5/3'`)
5. Use `BuildUpMath` with argument `0` to produce the math notation

[image]

For general expressions replace step 3 with a printing visitor on the expression's parse tree.

Note that steps 3 and 5 are not intended for TeX but for the [Unicode Nearly Plain-Text Encoding of Mathematics](http://www.unicode.org/notes/tn28/UTN28-PlainTextMath-v2.pdf), which is a derived format. The reason to use this format is that, at least in my experience, only fairly simple TeX expressions got correctly rendered. Of course, it would be worth giving it a try. In such case, use the TeX format (as far as I know LaTeX is not supported, so in the example `\dfrac{5}{3}` should be written as `{5 \over 3}`) and the `tomTeX` constant (`=1`) instead of `0` as the argument of `BuildUpMath`.

Here is a TeX example:

[image]

which I produced from the expression:

```
$\int_{-\infty}^\pi {x_0\over {\sqrt{y_0^{t^2} + 1}} + {5\over 3}}\; dt$
```

Another thing to keep in mind when using this feature is that it requires RichEdit version 6+, which comes with recent versions of Office.

Finally, after some experimentation I realized that only two modules are needed for this to work: `RICHED20.dll` and `MSPTLS.DLL`, the first one not to be confused with the dll that comes with Windows. Look for them in

```
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE16
```

Comment: How do you parse the latex?

Comment: You don't parse it, you produce it from a syntax tree of your mathematical expression, which is made up of objects representing operations, functions and arguments. In my experience, even though LaTex is supported, I found it that [this](http://www.unicode.org/notes/tn28/UTN28-PlainTextMath-v2.pdf) derived format works better.

Comment: The asker wants to put latex source as input and have it rendered as math. Can you do that with a rich edit control as your answer implies.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, that's my understanding and what I'm trying to say is that you should use `SetText` with the LaTeX source to get it rendered with `BuildUpMath`. The detail is that in that case the argument should be `tomTeX (=1)` instead of `0` but, in my experience, this didn't work very well so I used the derived (simplified) format whose manual is in the link of my previous comment.